# JNI How to store char arrray and Log it in jNI?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm sending char[] from java to C .I want to store the return value of my methodid function :

```
mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "getReg_chal", "()[C");
char[] reg_chal = (*env)-> ?
```

I'm referring the following example as refrence:

```
jmethodID midGetName = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, employeeClass, "getAge", "()I");
    int age =  (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, employeeObject, midGetName);
    return age;
```

What will i write in ? ... since CallCharArrayMethod is not available in JNI.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CallObjectMethod() would be work. see http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t140355-jni-calling-methods-that-return-byte.html  and http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16656